# How to get the javascript function that return string in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I wanted to toast a return string from a JavaScript function in my android app, I've been searching and tried some codes for days now but seems that I got no luck to find a correct one.

Here is the JS function that I want to be called in android to return a string value

```
function myFunction()
    {
        var str= document.getElementsByName('txt')[0].value;    
        window.android.myFunction(str); 
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
        //create interface
        JsInterface jsInterface = new JsInterface();

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //add interface
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "android");//android is the keyword that will be exposed in js

        //load file
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myFunction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);        
    }

    //javascript interface
    private class JsInterface{
        public String myFunction(String msg){
            return msg;
        }
    }
```

I'm a newbie to this kind of platform and also in Javascript. I appreciate those who'll answer. thanks.

Comment: Please search in google for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change in your code the following:

1. Run your JavaScript function from `WebViewClient.onPageFinished` to make sure that the document has actually loaded, and in order to run it, use `loadUrl()` function with a `javascript:` URL:

   ```
   wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       @Override
       void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction();void(0);");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Annotate the Java method you want to expose with `@JavascriptInterface` annotation (and make it `void`, as you don't actually want to return anything back to JavaScript), and call `Toast.makeText()` from inside it, but make sure you switch to the UI thread, because injected Java methods run on a dedicated background thread:

   ```
   private class JsInterface {
       private Context mContext;

       JsInterface(Context context) {
           mContext = context;
       }

       @JavascriptInterface
       public void myFunction(String msg) {
           new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
3. And just pass the application context to `JsInterface` upon creation:

   ```
   JsInterface jsInterface = new JsInterface(getApplicationContext());
   ```

Also note that you have two functions named `myFunction` in your JavaScript: the one in the injected object, available via `android.myFunction()`, and the one you have defined yourself, it is available as just `myFunction()` or `window.myFunction()`. It is actually better to use different names for them to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail for this :) do you mean I should change the function like this...  `function myFunction()
    {
        var str= document.getElementsByName('txt')[0].value;    
        window.getFunction(str); 
    }` in the Javascript?

Comment: It works perfectly now :D I just removed the `if condition` inside `void onPageFinished` Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer. Glad it works, sorry I didn't have time yesterday to try it :)